# How to add header with empty value to the http response (Response.Headers)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

I want to integrate my web site with office online by using WOPI protocol. I use asp.net core(3.0) web API to implement WOPI server. According the protocol documentation: https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/Unlock.html : :

> Response Headers
>           X-WOPI-Lock – A string value identifying the current lock on the file. **This header must always be included when responding to the
>   request with 409 Conflict.**

When file is not locked and I got request to unlock it, I need to response "409 Conflict"
with header that contains empty value: **X-WOPI-Lock: ""**

I tried to use:

> ```
> [ApiController]
> public class filesController : ControllerBase
> {
>
>     [HttpPost]
>     [Route("wopi/files/{id}")]
>     public IActionResult Post(Guid id)
>     {
>         var result = new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
>         HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-WOPI-Lock", string.Empty);
>         return result;
>     } }
> ```

and look like asp.net core ignore empty header, because it not present on the client, i see it by using Microsoft validation tool for WOPI
[image]

If I add some test value to the header, it appeared in the response:

> HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-WOPI-Lock", "Some value");

In the validation tool I see an error:
[image]

Look like, I need to create a http response that contains a header with empty value : **X-WOPI-Lock: ""**.

How can I do this?

Comment: `HttpResponseMessage` is not ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Try to use whitespace

Comment: 1. Apart from what said by @poke, even if you you're using ASP.NET Classic instead of ASP.NET Core, it returns a `X-WOPI-Lock: ` for me. Could you please show us a way to reproduce the same issue? 2. If you're using ASP.NET Core instead of ASP.NET Classic, change your code to `public void Unlock(){HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-WOPI-Lock", String.Empty);}`

Comment: Sorry HttpResponseMessage I wrote by memory, too long work with MVC :).
I updated my post with real code.

Comment: Thank You, Anton.
Solution is work for me:
  HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-WOPI-Lock", " ");

Comment: I the same issue yesterday, in the exact same scenario (WOPI validation tests). It was working fine in ASP.NET Core 2.1. I tracked down the cause of the issue to [this pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/12486): when the app is hosted on IIS, empty headers are omitted from the response. Using whitespace instead of an empty string works, but I don't know for how long... Anyway, the real issue is probably in the WOPI tests. The WOPI specs mention that the header can be omitted if the file is not locked, but the validation tests require it.